# I updated node, but I still get Promise.allSettled is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

### EDIT: Resolved- My issue was that even though node -v worked, and everything said it was working, my node was still pointing to node 10, even though it thought it was at node 12.  UNinstalling and reinstalling node and nvm fixed it.

I do not have enough points to comment on a similar question, so that is why I am creating a new one:

I am on node version 12.20.1 (changed from 10.15.3), but I still get `TypeError: Promise.allSettled is not a function`
Here is the snippet:

```
return Promise.allSettled(
    result.succeededDocuments.map((asyncActionArray) => {
        //do stuff
    })
)
```

I keep changing node versions, I restart my computer, I run yarn just in case, but I am at a loss as to why I cannot get it to work.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does `node -v` confirm your version?

Comment: Node added this in 12.9. How sure are you that you're using the version you think you are?

Comment: Is your `package.json` using the global `node` command, or does it possibly use an installation local to the project?

Comment: Or are you possibly using nvm with an nvmrc in your project and overriding the version of Node you think you're on? Besides `node -v` you could also add a `console.log(process.version)` right above your function.

Comment: @JaredSmith - How do you figure out what version of node.js, something like this that is built into V8, showed up in nodejs?

Comment: @jfriend00 I was going by [this table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/), which is my usual goto along with caniuse.

Comment: @JaredSmith - Thx.  I forgot about that resource.  I was thinking you were looking at some nodejs specific resource.

Comment: Make sure your Typescript definitions are up to date to match your node version